# Integrate both sides with different limits, is it legit?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

My question arise from physics, however I'm interested in the mathematical justification of the following integration.

In the derivation of a equation of motion with constant acceleration, $a$, ([link to page](https://physics.info/kinematics-calculus/)) the author integrate both sides of an equation with **different** limits.
Is this integration really mathematically correct (my equation $3$)?

> \begin{align}
> a&=\frac{dv(t)}{dt}\tag 1\\
> \implies dv &= a\, dt \tag 2\\
> \int_{v_i}^{v} dv &= \int_0^t  a \, dt \tag 3\\
> v-v_i&=a(t-0)=at \tag 4\\
> v&=v_i+at \tag 5
> \end{align}

Aren't we supposed to integrate both sides with the same limits?

Comment: no, they're different differentials. one is dv the other is dt

Comment: Ah mate, this is the classical question. Still have no answer to that one honestly ^^

Comment: @user29418 This is very unhelpful. Of course they are different symbols, but equation (2) expresses an equality between $dv$ and $a \; dt$. Why should we expect equation (3) to hold, which seems to equate two different integrals of the same differential form? What's going on here is that the integrals actually do have the exact same bounds; the notation is just poorly chosen.

Comment: You are integrating over time, then taking the value of the velocity as a function of time on the left side, and the time as a function of time (the identity) on the right side

Comment: @diracdeltafunk yes they're the same bounds but not the same limits as in they're both not the same numbers

Answer (score 3):

First, you shouldn't use the same variable both for the upper limits and the differentials. Thus, I'll make the equation $$\int_{v_i}^{v_f}{\mathrm d v}=\int_0^T{a \mathrm dt}.$$

Note that as $t$ goes from $0$ to $T,$ $v$ also varies correspondingly between $v_i$ and $v_f.$

What's just happened follows from the differential equation $$\mathrm d v =a \mathrm dt.$$ This equation says the differentials are equal for each $v$ corresponding to $t.$ It then follows that their integrals between corresponding intervals would also be equal.

Answer (score 2):

Let's start with the claim that the limits should be the same. If we take this quite literally the units do not work out properly. ($t = \frac{l}{t}$) We are then forced to ask what we mean when we say the limits should be the same.

I believe equation (2) is a bit of short hand that requires you to know what's going on behind the scenes. When solving (1) you could integrate both sides with respect to $t$:
$$\int_0^Ta\cdot dt = \int_0^T\frac{dv}{dt}dt$$
at this point you can do a $u$-substitution on the right hand side where $u=v(t)$. This would give us:
$$\int_0^Ta\cdot dt = \int_{v(0)}^{v(T)} du$$

Another take you have on solving your original problem is that you could start with the indefinite integrals to get:
$$v(t)+A= a t + B$$
$$v(t)= a t + (B-A)$$
you could then solve for $(B-A)$ given that they are constants of integration and you should know $v(t=0)$.

This solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is basically $u$-substitution spelled out in such a way that it reveals the notational quirks in the way we teach calculus. Start with the right-hand side and set $u = v(t)$. Crank the $u$-sub machine in the mechanical way you learned from school and you get the left-hand side. The bounds are secretly exactly the same!

Answer (score 1):

When the differential is $dt$, you integrate on $t$ and the bounds are $0$ and $t$.

When the differential is $dv$, you integrate on $v$ and the bounds are the corresponding values of $v$, i.e. $v(0)$ and $v(t)$. Just like with a change of variable.

Answer (score 0):

you should write v1=v(0) and vf=v(T)
also on the left side you add velocities, on the right side, you add time-intervalls times accelerations .
trula